# Slick Slider Wordpress Custom Post Type

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have a static slick slider which I use to run testimonials on, instead of being hard typed I want to pull them from WordPress custom post type which I have set up can someone point me in the right direction:

```
<section class="testimonials">
    <div class="container text-center">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="slick-testimonial">
                    <div class="item">
                        <div class="testimonial">
                            <img src="<?php  bloginfo('template_url');  ?>/images/icons/testimonals.png" class="center-block">
                            <h1>What our customers say</h1>
                            <h3>"Fantastic service"</h3>
                            <p>Review Text Here</p>
                            <p class="name">Customer Name 1</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <div class="testimonial">
                            <img src="<?php  bloginfo('template_url');  ?>/images/icons/testimonals.png" class="center-block">
                            <h1>What our customers say</h1>
                            <h3>"Excellent"</h3>
                            <p>Review Text Here</p>
                            <p class="name">Customer Name 2</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

i believe i need to pull up an array for the custom post type and in the item pull the title name and text but not sure how to write it thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to interact with WordPress' [WP_Query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/) Class. It's the de facto way to get a handful of posts.

I'd also consider restructuring your slider a bit so the "What our Customers Say" is *outside* the individual slide item, but I digress:

All you have to do is set up a new `WP_Query` and replace the `item` div with a simple `while` loop:

```
<?php
    $slider_args  = array(
        'post_type'      => 'testimonials',
        'posts_per_page' => 10
    );

    $slider_query = new WP_Query( $slider_args );
?>
<section class="testimonials">
    <div class="container text-center">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="slick-testimonial">
                    <?php
                        if( $slider_query->have_posts() ){
                            while( $slider_query->have_posts() ){ $slider_query->the_post(); ?>
                                <div class="item">
                                    <div class="testimonial">
                                        <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url');  ?>/images/icons/testimonals.png" class="center-block">
                                        <h1>What our customers say</h1>
                                        <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                                        <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>
                                        <p class="name"><?php echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'reviewer_name', true ); ?></p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            <?php }
                        } else { ?>
                            <div class="item">
                                <div class="testimonial">
                                    <h3>No Testimonials Found</h3>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        <?php }
                        wp_reset_postdata();
                    ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Note that this code makes a few assumptions. You'll need to replace the `post_type` with the name of the CPT you have registered, and you can adjust how many to get with the `posts_per_page` argument. I picked 10 just because.

This also assumes you're saving the Reviewer Name in a meta field named `reviewer_name`, but it should be enough to get you started

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply this really helped and it is now working the way I want it to work!

Comment: Great, glad to help! Would you mind marking the answer as accepted (clicking the checkmark) so it may better help others with similar issues?

Comment: Also it most certainly would. Give the [`WP_Query`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/) a read for how to really dive into it - but in essence you just replace `post_type` with whatever post type you'd like to get (if you omit it, it defaults to Posts as well)